# Is it possible to have a backslash by itself in preformatted text? How?

Tags: support, markdown-rendering

Recently when writing a comment, I tried to put a backslash (\) by itself in preformatted text (surrounded by `).

I couldn't find a way to make that work.

With a single backslash: `\` - this apparently works in posts, but in a comment on Stack Overflow, I just got two backticks as normal text.

Doubling up the backslash didn't work either - I get a backslash and backticks, in normal text. My best guess is that Markdown prefers to escape the closing backtick rather than the backslash, and so the intended opening backtick is now unpaired.

Any workarounds for this?

Comment: Testing a single backslash between backticks in a comment here: `\`.

Comment: [Yep](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/289905#comment1174312_3122): [SOBotics Tool](//tools.sobotics.org/tools/get-body-comment/) to get the source text of this comment. Single backslash and single backtick: ``\``, `\``. Type: `\`\`\\`\`, \`\\`\``.

Comment: I appreciate that there are apparently like a million duplicates for this, but none of them came up when I searched what I thought were the obvious terms. Maybe I'm just tired.

Comment: Anyway, I find it bizarre that comments handle this differently... as a side effect of not supporting some entirely unrelated Markdown features that only make sense in multiple-line posts? What?